# A bug in gfortran-4.9 (and newer)?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I think I found a bug in gfortran-4.9 and newer. It occurs when you have a module with some name (lets name it `init`) and it uses a module with an aliased subroutine or function with the same name (`init`) - see the code bellow.

I encountered it when trying to compile my old code with a newer version of gfortran (gfortran-5.3 in my case). I tried to compile with older versions and found that this occurs in gfortran-4.9 but not at gfortran-4.7. Then I also used newer versions of gfortran, and the newest version I could get was 8.1. The bug occurs in it too.

So, should I report this bug? Or it isn't even a bug but a part of a newer fortran standart that i don't know? Also, if this is a bug, can someone try to compile the code bellow using gfortran-9 to see if it's still there.

The code, that reproduces the bug:

```
!------the part below could be the contents of another file -----    
module mod
  implicit none
contains
  subroutine init
    write(*,*) "Hello!"
  end subroutine init
end module mod

module test_mod
  use mod, only : test_init => init
end module test_mod
!-----------------------------------------------------

module init ! the name of the module (init) is the same as the name of
            ! aliased subroutine in used module (test_mod)
  use test_mod
  implicit none
contains
  subroutine test_sub
    call test_init
  end subroutine test_sub
end module init

program test
  use init
  implicit none
  call test_sub
end program test
```

EDIT: When I compile this code on gfortran version from 4.9 to 8.1 I get the following error message

```
 
call test_init

internal compiler error: in conv_function_val, at fortran/trans-expr.c:3792
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-8/README.Bugs for instructions.
```

EDIT2: Bug report link: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=89574. The bug appears in all versions of gfortran since 4.9.

Comment: You did not tell us how does the bug exhibit! Wee need the error message. I think it may be already known and present in bugzilla. I certainly met something similar with bind(C) binding names.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take your time to take the [tour] and learn [ask]. You should include the result (or the error) you obtained with the provided code. With `gfortran 8.2` on Mac I get an *Internal Compiler Error*. An ICE is always a compiler bug, and you should definitely report it [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/buglist.cgi?bug_status=__open__&component=fortran&product=gcc) (remember to search for duplicates first, you can see instructions on reporting [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugs/)). Plus, `ifort 19` compiles it just fine.

Comment: Yeah, just do what the error message says: *"Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate."* That means submit to GCC, not just here. I did not find a duplicate, just https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=86051 but that is quite unclear.

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues I added the error message to the post. I tried to search for duplicates at bugzilla and didn't find any. So I will report it. Thanks.

Comment: @VladimirF Thanks, will do it now

Comment: The link https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=89574